# Jslint does not recognize option for misordered functions

Tags: javascript, jslint

I use JavaScript comment to set the options

```
/*jslint undef: false, browser: true */
```

to tolerate misordered function and variable definitions per the [jslint documentation here](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html).  I tried setting it to 'true' as well but this did not work either.

Yet I still get

> 'vFlipB' was used before it was defined.
>
> ```
>         vFlipB('mi_cover');
> ```

This function is first called here on line 299:

```
Mo.UserAny = {
    pre : function (o_p) {
        vFlipB('mi_cover');
        if ((localStorage.hash === '0') || (localStorage.hash === undefined) || (localStorage.hash === null)) {
            o_p.result = 'complete';
            Vi.Ani.flipP('sp');
            return o_p;
        }
```

.
.
.

But is not defind untill below it here:

on 958

```
/**
 **  vFlipB
 */

function vFlipB( current_id ) {

    // turn on

    var current_link = document.getElementById( current_id + '_l' ),
        current_box = document.getElementById( current_id );

    current_box.style.opacity = 1;
    current_link.style.borderBottom = '2px solid #31baed';   

    // turn off

    if( vFlipB.previous_box !== undefined && vFlipB.previous_box !== current_box ) {
        vFlipB.previous_box.style.opacity = 0;
        vFlipB.previous_link.style.borderBottom = '';  
    }

    // set current to static previous

    vFlipB.previous_box = current_box;
    vFlipB.previous_link = current_link;
}
```

Comment: can we see the rest of your code because this part is just fine

Comment: Could not get a fiddle up..so I just posted the two areas of the code.

Comment: why don't you just put the function before the line 299 part?

Comment: and where have you called the options for the jslint?

Comment: Just a comment at the top of the .js file - /*jslint undef: false, browser: true */

Comment: I don't want to re-order all my functions if I don't have to.

Comment: A generic comment: you might try jshint, which is a more configurable and less cranky fork of jslint. I can't say whether it will fix this problem, but it's worth a try anyway.

Comment: I pass jshint already...i want to pass jslint

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

`/*jslint undef: true, sloppy: true, browser: true */`

According to [the docs](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#options), the `undef` option is not available in strict mode. So you need to set `sloppy: true` (great name, huh?) and remove any `"use strict";` statement from the top of your JS file. (You also had the value of `undef` reversed).

Of course, there are [lots of](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1335881/1172352) [good reasons](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/01/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-in-firefox-4/) to use strict mode. If you want to avoid warnings but still use strict mode, you really only have three options:

- Use JSHint instead of JSLint
- Place `"use strict";` at the top of each individual function body instead of at the top of your file or module. (You can't put it inside your function that calls vFlipB() though – otherwise the warning will come back)
- Change your code to avoid calling a function that's defined lower down. You could reorder your code, split it into separate modules, or play a trick like this:

  ```
  var vFlipB;
  ...
  vFlipB();
  ...
  vFlipB = function () { ... };
  ```